# Find Time and Memory after program running in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, time

Is it any way in matlab that after program is finished to run, find the memory and time?
Also, if the workplace is saved and then it is loaded again, is it possible to see the time and memory for it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time consumption, would the [profiler](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) work? It slows the execution a bit, but is nice for debugging. Otherwise try to enclose the section you want to time with `tic`-`toc`.

And for memory consumption there were, and still is I think, no really convenient way to do this, however, something may have happened here. This is how [mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97560-how-can-i-monitor-how-much-memory-matlab-is-using) answered a few years ago. You can try `whos`, but that one only works inside the current scope. Also `memory` can be used to see matlabs total memory consumption.

The time taken for loading a file should be possible to see by enclosing it with the usual `tic`-`toc` command. The size of a saved file on disk can be seen using `dir` on the file, but the size could be different in matlab. I guess that the safest way is to check the size before saving if it will be loaded under the same execution and otherwise it may be convenient to log the size somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not related to my question. I mean you run a program. Then you save the workplace. Finally you re-start pc. Now, is it possible to see the time and memory that each function used in previous running ?

Comment: As the mathworks answer suggesting, the opportunity for getting this information is limited. I have given you some tools, it is then up to you how you implement it. I guess that it is time for you to start logging. And further, you have not even told me what information you need. Peak memory allocation, memory allocation for some functions that are called often...? Still, are you seriously thinking that you can run a program, reboot your PC and then in some magical retrieve the requested data. It is quite clear that you need to log it somehow. The requested information need to be **saved**

Comment: Perhaps @AliBodaghi DId not realize that it is possible to save the profile results. Here is a note on that: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92350-how-can-i-save-my-profiler-results-and-later-on-reload-the-data-in-the-profiler-gui-in-matlab-7-7-r

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if i got your question correctly, but if you need to trace the time your function takes there are two ways:

the functions

```
tic;
t=toc
```

work like a stopwatch, tic starts the counting and toc tells you how long passed since last tic.

if you need to do more in depth analysis of the times matlab also offers a `profile` function.
i suggest you go through matlab documentation on how to use it...

hope i helped.

S.

Answer (score 1):

For execution time between code lines use:

```
tic;
toc;
t = toc;
disp(['Execution time: ' num2str(t)])
```

To know and show memory usage of variables you can use `whos`

```
whos
S = whos;  % type struct variable containing all the info of the actual workspace
S.bytes
```

To calculate the total storage, you can make a loop

```
Memory = 0;
S = whos;
for k = 1:length(S)
    Memory = Memory + S(k).bytes;
end 
disp(['Total memory used by variables in storage (Bytes): ' num2str(Memory)])
```

You might prefer to see `whos` page in mathworks